# не могу определить правильную иерархию классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Дан следующий список классов:

```
class Character(BaseSprite):

class BaseSprite(pygame.spryte.Spryte):

class Enemy1(Enemy):

class Actor(Character):

class Enemy(Actor):
```

как правильно расставить их в иерархическом порядке?

Comment: Начините с поиска такого родительского класса, которого нет в классах-потомках. Найденный класс с таким предком принимаете за новый родительский. И так по кругу

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
import pygame

# ? class BaseSprite(pygame.spryte.Spryte):
class BaseSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'\nclass BaseSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):')
    
    
class Character(BaseSprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'class Character(BaseSprite):')
    
class Actor(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'class Actor(Character):')
    
    
class Enemy(Actor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'class Enemy(Actor):')
 
 
class Enemy1(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f'class Enemy1(Enemy):\n') #

enemy1 = Enemy1()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]